# IDA: How to get proper opcode to jump to choosen subroutine

Tags: android, c, assembly, arm, ida

I have disassembled `camera.msm8953.so` file using IDA PRO and I want to change one jump - BLX `convertMipiToRaw16` to `convertLegacyToRaw16`, but I can't find proper opcode for that subroutine.

Is there any method to get it? I have searched through the file and this subroutine was never called before.

Comment: `blx` is encoded with a relative offset (or a register). The opcode is the same. Copying the bytes from another, eventual, call site to `convertLegacyToRaw16` and pasting them somewhere else won't work because the displacement won't match (or the register used is still not correctly set). You have to encode the instruction yourself or with the help of an assembler.

Comment: Using branch calculator I have managed to make `B convertLegacyToRaw16` but I can't calculate proper opcode for `BLX` I'm getting three `DCB` instructions instead.
If I calculate opcode for `BLX convertMipiToRaw16` it is working fine tho.

Comment: I don't know why but IDA was showing wrong instructions after hex edits, but afrer aplying patch and opening file again it showed `BLX convertLegacyToRaw16` :)